# How do I make axios post request with body and form data simultaneously?

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I want to send a post rquest with axios that has body data and form data and I can get anything to reach through to my route hadler:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${keys.SERVER_URL}/post/new-post/${isAuthenticated()._id}`,
    formData,
    data: { title, content },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
});
```

then in the route handler I `console.log` and I get nothing:

```
app.post("/new-post", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file):
});
```

Comment: Skoltz,  thanks for the your meaningful contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `formData` option for the `axios()` options object.  If you want to set `formData`, you set the `data` property to your formData.

So, that illustrates that there is ONLY one set of data that you send with a POST or a PUT.  If you want to send multiple pieces of data, you have to combine them into the same set of data and you have to obviously make them the same type of data (since there is only one master content-type).  If you really needed to send multiple different types of data, then you would need to send a multi-part body that has separate sections to it.  You would likely need some sort of helper to create that multi-part body since that isn't something that axios will do for you and it can get a little complicated.

If you could describe what you're actually trying to do (what the actual purpose of this request is), then we might be able to advise how to combine your data into one simpler type so it an be sent more simply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I want to create a post object, like a blog post, that has a title, some content and an image. For the title and content is easy to send a POST request with the title and content. Is also fairly easy to send an image with a POST request via a FormData. And I managed to achieve both of these actions successfully, but in separate requests. 
My problem is that I can't make a single POST request with title, content and FormData altogether, so that I can access them on express server with req.body or req.file.

Comment: @TarasiCristiAndrei - I would suggest adding the title and content as individual formData elements along with your other formData so you can just send formData.  formData is a modifyable object which you can add things to.

Comment: Cheers mate. Thanks to your sugestion I was able to solve this. I appreciate it. Good luck.

Comment: @TarasiCristiAndrei - Glad you got it figured out.  Please take note for future questions that I was best able to come up with a simple suggestion only when you described the actual problem you were trying to solve rather than a problem you ran into with the solution you were trying.  This is known as the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as it slows down our ability to help.